# How to trap and get value from a redirected URL in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am using angular.js as front end and node.js as backend,Now i am calling a URL which is mentioned below in button click event in my local home page.

Sample URL :

https://locahost:3000/auth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=abzefcbbkjajsdd&scope=userfetchit&redirect_uri=localhost&nonce=32324

When i called the above URL it's shows login page in new window and after i given the email and password it's redirected to another URL which is mentioned below

Redirected URL:

https://localhost:3000/auth/localhost?code=8dacae52ee284db3dc776aa6d3563912

Expected result :

Now, i want to get the code value "8dacae52ee284db3dc776aa6d3563912" from the above URL in angular.js.

HTML code :

```
<html ng-app='app' ng-controller='LoginController'>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <button type="button"

                class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  ng-click="tokenLogin()">
                     New Login 
                </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <pre>{{ cleanData | json}}</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Controller code :

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('LoginController', ['$location','$window','$scope', '$filter', function($location,$window,$scope, $filter) {
$scope.tokenLogin = function() {

            var url = 'https://localhost:3000/auth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=abzefcbbkjajsdd&scope=userfetchit&redirect_uri=localhost&nonce=32324';
            $window.open(url);

        };

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to add the code parameter in your `$stateProvider` like this:

```
.state('yourstate', {
  url: '/localhost?:code',
  templateUrl: 'localhost.html'
});
```

Then in your controller you can call:

```
console.log($stateParams.code);
```

And that's it. You can set this value to scope variable or anything.

Comment: While i called the old URL it's entirely redirected to new page that page(login page) rendered from server.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying but what ever your code and situation is you can catch the current url parameters of the state that is active the way I demonstrated above.

Comment: Can you make a plunker out of this thing? Or perhaps show more code like your app.js?

Comment: i accept that we can catch current URL parameter ,but in my scenario while call the URL  (https://locahost:3000/auth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=abzefcbbkjajsdd&scope=userfetchit&redirect_uri=localhost&nonce=32324) it's redirected to the new window (login page) this login page is not rendered from in my local it's rendered from server. for more please give your skype ID i will ping you.

Comment: Hi Thepio in plunker i have added app.js code http://plnkr.co/edit/qaXkoKoycTku5crh9LXb?p=preview

Comment: my skype id "siva.p07" please let me know once you checked